# Random lines away from images in java2d opengl game

Tags: opengl, java, slick

Working on a java game that uses some pngs images for icons/textures. A few images ( fewer than 5, out of dozens ) are showing some odd parallel "artifact" lines. They move with the image, are certainly not in the PNG itself.

I can't figure out what's causing it. Using slick2d, lwjgl. I've tried slcik2d and opengl methods of clamping textures but that didn't help.

[image]

This black line is showing off the right-hand side of an icon (maybe 50% of the actual image width away). It should not be there.

Comment: Are you doing any graphics.translate(x, y) calls? Because I've had the same problem before and I fixed it before in my own game

Answer (score 1):

i think that is because textures are loading using power of 2.
and you are probably using the texture width and height to render the image onto a quad. 
what you should do instead is use the images relative size from withing the texture.

it should be a floating point number such as 0.67080760(or something) since 1f would be the total width and height of your image.

I only say this because i ran into the same problem when i started working with lwjgl(ive never used slick2d but its based on lwjgl) and what i suggested fixed the image irregularity.